# How to retrieve all indexes in a database along with their data types in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, maintenance-plan

I have a maintenance task that's failing because there are a few indexes on the database that have a type which does not allow online rebuilding of the index. Offline is not an option in my industry, so I have to create my own T-SQL task that does the index rebuilding on specific indexes. The database is large with many tables and indexes, so is there a way to query the system for all indexes and their data types?

Comment: Pretty sure [both of these solutions I mention here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/is-staggering-reindexing-jobs-a-good-strategy-mssql/11390#comment16991_11390) take account of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show you all the columns for all indices, including the columns of 'base tables' like heaps and clustered index and all `INCLUDE` columns as well:

```
select o.name as [object_name],
    ix.name as [index_name],
    coalesce(c.name,cc.name) as [column_name],
    t.name as [type_name],
    coalesce(c.max_length, cc.max_length) as max_length
from sys.indexes ix
join sys.objects o
    on ix.object_id = o.object_id
left join sys.index_columns ic
    on ix.object_id = ic.object_id
    and ix.index_id = ix.index_id
    and ix.index_id > 1
left join sys.columns c
    on  ic.object_id = c.object_id
    and ic.column_id = c.column_id
left join sys.columns cc
    on ix.object_id = cc.object_id
    and ix.index_id in (1,0)
join sys.types t
    on t.system_type_id = coalesce(c.system_type_id,cc.system_type_id)  
where o.type = 'U'
order by object_name, index_name, column_name;
```

You can then identify the ones unsafe for online index rebuild (the BLOB/XML/CLR types). Note that in SQL server 2012 the restriction on online index build with LOB columns was lifted, see [Online Index Operations for indexes containing LOB columns](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/).

Answer (score 0):

we've made recently such procedure. it has "HasBlobs" flag for this purpose

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_rebuild_local_idexes
@RebuildClustered bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @objectid int
    DECLARE @indexid int
    DECLARE @schemaname nvarchar(130)
    DECLARE @objectname nvarchar(130)
    DECLARE @indexname nvarchar(130)
    DECLARE @partitions bigint
    DECLARE @frag float
    DECLARE @command nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @HasBlobs bit
    DECLARE @index_type_desc nvarchar(255)

    -- Conditionally select tables and indexes from the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats function
    -- and convert object and index IDs to names.

    SELECT
    --object_name(object_id),
    object_id AS objectid,
    index_id AS indexid,
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS frag,
    CASE WHEN (
        SELECT st.object_id
            from sys.tables st
            inner join sys.columns sc
                on st.object_id=sc.object_id
            inner join sys.types styp
                on sc.system_type_id=styp.system_type_id and sc.max_length=styp.max_length
            inner join sys.schemas ss
                on st.schema_id=ss.schema_id
            where styp.schema_id=4
                    and styp.name<>'sysname'
                    and styp.name IN ('xml','nvarchar','varchar','image','text','ntext')
                    AND st.object_id = a.object_id
            group by st.object_id
    )  IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasBlobs,
    a.index_type_desc
    INTO #work_to_do
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED') AS a
    WHERE avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 5.0 AND index_id > 0
              AND a.index_type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED INDEX','NONCLUSTERED INDEX')           
    ORDER BY a.index_type_desc

    -- Declare the cursor for the list of partitions to be processed.
    DECLARE partitions CURSOR FOR SELECT objectid,
            indexid,
            frag,
            HasBlobs,
            index_type_desc from #work_to_do
select * from #work_to_do
    -- Open the cursor.
    OPEN partitions

    -- Loop through the partitions.
    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM partitions
        INTO @objectid, @indexid, @frag,@HasBlobs,@index_type_desc

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK

        IF @RebuildClustered = 1 AND @index_type_desc != 'CLUSTERED INDEX'
            CONTINUE;

        SELECT @objectname = QUOTENAME(o.name), @schemaname = QUOTENAME(s.name)
        FROM sys.objects AS o
        JOIN sys.schemas as s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        WHERE o.object_id = @objectid

        SELECT @indexname = QUOTENAME(name)
        FROM sys.indexes
        WHERE object_id = @objectid AND index_id = @indexid and type!=3

        -- 30 is an arbitrary decision point at which to switch between reorganizing and rebuilding.
        IF @frag < 30.0
            SET @command = N'ALTER INDEX ' + @indexname + N' ON ' + @schemaname + N'.' + @objectname + N' REORGANIZE'

        IF @frag >= 30.0
        BEGIN
            print @indexname+ @schemaname+@objectname
            SET @command = N'ALTER INDEX ' + @indexname +
                            N' ON ' +
                            @schemaname +
                            N'.' + @objectname +
                            N' REBUILD' +
                            CASE WHEN @HasBlobs = 0 THEN ' WITH(ONLINE=ON)' ELSE '' END
            print @command
        END

        EXEC (@command)
        PRINT N'Executed: ' + @command


    END

    -- Close and deallocate the cursor.
    CLOSE partitions
    DEALLOCATE partitions
END
```

---